# Where can I learn more about market-making strategies?

Tags: hedging, algorithmic-trading, market-making, liquidity

I have some experience trading both sides of an order book, but not simultaneously in the same security (and certainly not at the size large market makers do.)

I've searched pretty extensively for books on the topic, but there isn't really a "strategies for market makers" type of textbook out there in something like the Wiley Finance series, in the same way that there are a huge number of fixed income texts or for other topics.

I have managed to find a few papers, but does anybody have a suggestion for one comprehensive resource that I want to look at, or even just which branch of finance I want to be looking in for a start?

Eg - algorithmic trading strategies, or market microstructure theory? Etc.

Thank you.